# how to solve a singular integral equation involving the kernel $1/x$

Tags: integral-transforms, differential-equations, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities

Dear all,

Suppose we know that $f(x)$ is nonnegative and Hölder continuous at zero with exponents $1/2$. We also know that

$$
f(x) \le g(x) + \int_0^x \frac{f(y)}{y} d y,\quad\forall x>0,
$$

where $g(x)$ is some nonnegative nice function, for example, $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Is it possible to derive a good upper bound for $f(x)$? Apparently, classical [Gronwall's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality) doesn't work since $1/y$ is not integrable around $0$.

EDIT:
Just to make it clear, I wish to have a upper bound of the following form: For fixed $c>0$,

$$
\sup_{x\in [0,c] } f(x)\le  ?
$$

Thank you very much for any hints and help! :-)

Comment: On your "edit": both answers show 
that this sup can be as large as you wish.

Comment: Dear Professor Eremenko, you are right. Some other conditions are needed.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

No upper bound can be derived, good or bad. Take $f(x)=cx$ where $c$ is large positive.
Your inequality is trivially satisfied.

Comment: THanks Alexandre Eremenko, What I want is $\sup_{0\le x\le c} f(x)$ for fixed $c>0$.

Comment: To be precise, the function $f(x)=cx$ is not 1/2 Hölder on $[0,+\infty)$ as it was assumed in the question. But $cx^{1/2}$ works, of course.

Comment: $f(x)=c x$ is even $1$ Hölder continuous which is stronger than 1/2 Hölder continuous. :-)

Comment: Well, that depends on the definition :-) To me $f:X\to\bf R$ being $\alpha$ Hölder means $|f(x)-f(y)| \le C|x-y|^\alpha$ for *all* $x$ and $y$ in $X$. I'd call "locally Hölder" a function like $x\mapsto cx$ on $[0,+\infty)$.


Answer (score 1):

Note that the inequality is satisfied by the functions $f(x)=cx^{1/2}$, for any $c\ge0$ and any nonnegative $g$. So, in terms of upper bounds, it doesn't really add anything to the information that $f$ is Hölder continuous of exponent 1/2.

Comment: Thanks Professor Pietro Majer, do you think that there can be some Gronwall type inequality for this case? Adding Hölder continuity is to make sure the integral is well defined.
